# String to unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I've been reading some articles about unicode ([this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and [this](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)), but still don't understand how to do something as simple as this (in python 2.7):

From

```
x = 'm\\u00e1s'
```

I want to obtain the unicode string `u'm\u00e1s'` ("más").

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Help us understand your problem better. How did you obtain the string with the bad data in it? Why can't you simply say `x = u'm\u00e1s'` ?

Comment: Sorry, it was an error, now it is fixed

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo in `u'm\e...`. But this certainly seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, another article to read is [Pragmatic Unicode, or How Do I Stop the Pain?](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html).

Comment: It was more like an exercise to try to understand the encoding/decoding, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal answer to your question is to decode your original string using the `raw_unicode_escape` codec.

```
In [2]: x = 'm\\u00e1s'

In [3]: x.decode('raw_unicode_escape')
Out[3]: u'm\xe1s'
```

But that's almost certainly the wrong way to do whatever you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

```
x = 'm\\u00e1s'
unicode(x)
```

gives:

```
u'm\\u00e1s'
```

Comment: I'm after `u'm\e00e1s'` (only one '\'). If I `print u'm\e00e1s'` it gives me "más", if I `print u'm\\u00e1s'` it gives me "m\u00e1s"